# j2me appending a form after form with same fields... suggest me

Tags: java-me

what i exactly trying to do is appending a form after form with same fields so i can perform calculation eachtime on the containts by saving them to a an array or just adding after each new append form.... suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the solution myself
deleting the old fields and appending the new fields with the same properties
worked for me nicely....